# How to change ngModel bind Value from mat-select dropdown options

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular-material2

I tried to ngModel bind value in mat-select dropdown.I have some value in options ex: A - A/C Loss, B - BURGLARY.
Once i checked option checkbox i need to bind only A,B remove A/C Loss and BURGLARY.

This is options value example:
[image]
This is ngModel bind value example:
[image]
Need to exactly result in ngModel: A,B,CF,CI,CM,CR

Code Example:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select Events" [formControl]="selectEventitems" [(ngModel)]="selectedEventValue" (change)="onEventsChange($event)" (focus)="onEventfocus($event)" multiple>
     <mat-option class="select-all" value="SelectAll">Select All</mat-option>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let event of getAllEvents" [value]="event.eventrpt_id">{{event.eventrpt_id}} - {{event.descr}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select Events" [formControl]="selectEventitems" [(ngModel)]="selectedEventValue" (change)="onEventsChange($event)" (focus)="onEventfocus($event)" multiple>
     <mat-option class="select-all">Select All</mat-option>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let event of getAllEvents" [value]="event.eventrpt_id">{{event.eventrpt_id}} - {{event.descr}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```